# Valid formulas of a formal system?

Tags: logic

Is the expression "valid formulas of a formal system" correct? I've been reading recently some some lecture notes where the expression "valid formulas of a formal system" is used (with reference to predicate calculus). I thought that you can use the expression "valid formula" only when you talk about a formal language, not a formal system; that is, I thought that "valid formula" is a semantic concept not a syntactic one. Could someone help me?

Comment: What is the def of [formal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) ?

Comment: Usually "valid" is defined according to a semantics for the language.

Comment: But someone cam mean with "valid formula" a *theorem*, i.e. a formula that is derivable from the axioms of the system by way of the inference rules, irerspective of the interpretation.

Comment: Formal system = a formal language + a set of inference rules and, possibly, a set of axioms.

Comment: Agreed; thus my third comment (as well as Henning's full answer) applies.

Comment: Nope, valid formulas are not theorems in the notes I'm reading, because the distinction is made between valid formulas and theorems. This is pretty confusing.

Comment: See the post [are-axioms-assumed-to-be-true-in-a-formal-system](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871909/are-axioms-assumed-to-be-true-in-a-formal-system) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You're right: Usually "valid" when applied to logical formulas will mean "logically valid", that is, it describes formulas that are true for every possible interpretation of the non-logical symbols in them.

However, from time to time writers will slip and use "valid" in its everyday non-technical meaning of "allowed by the rules" - which may well be the case for the instance you have found. If that is so, your "valid formulas" would just mean "well-formed formulas" (in the language of the system).

But we cannot say for sure without knowing more context of your quote.

Comment: No, it's not just "well-formed formulas" because in fact the author talks about the "logically valid formulas of predicate calculus"!

Comment: All this is pretty confusing.

Comment: @Fishermansfriend: If that's the context, then it's definitely the technical concept of "logically valid". Don't put too much weight on "of predicate calculus" -- that is just used as a reference to the _language_ of pure predicate calculus (presumably with a countably infinite supply of predicate and function symbols of each arity).