# Is First Order logic an axiomatic system?

Tags: first-order-logic

Is FOL a *formal* system or a *formal* **axiomatic** system? That is, is there anything in FOL apart from syntax, semantics and inference rules? Or do the syntactic rules count as axioms?

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close - I think this question is sufficiently focused and admits a good answer (and incidentally stems from the regrettable over-loading of the term "formal system"). I've voted to reopen.

Comment: See [FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

Comment: FOL is a language (syntax rules) + semantics (definition of interpretation) + proof calculus. There are many different way to set up a proof calculus: someone with axioms and rules and some (like Natural Deduction a Truth Trees) with only rules.

Comment: Thus, the presence of **axioms** is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Maybe useful the post [Axiom Systems and Formal Systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408131/axiom-systems-and-formal-systems) as well as [Are axioms assumed to be true in a formal system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871909/are-axioms-assumed-to-be-true-in-a-formal-system)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you for your response! this is very helpful